Macbook preview resets to first page on recompiling the corresponding latex file
I use PyCharm TeXiFy-IDEA plugin to edit my latex files and see the PDF in preview app. However, everytime I compile my latex file, Preview opens the first page of the document and I have to scroll to my previously opened page. Is it possible to make Preview not reset to first page and continue showing the previously opened page?
This is exactly the issue described in  this post in apple discussions forum. I have configured preview to open the last viewed page on opening a document as shown in the below figure.

Update 01-May-2024:
I installed SKIM viewer which supports what I want. It supports forward and backward search, too. Appears to be more stable than the Preview app. As of today, PyCharm has an inbuilt PDF viewer, too.

Thanks! That makes sense. Couldn't find if Preview uses synctex. This post says that it may not, but does not confirm the same. I tried the SKIM pdf viewer. Seems good for now. On the other hand, synctex support is probably not necessary to do what I want. The viewer can note down the page num before reloading the document and simply scroll to that page. Based on that discussion in the apple forum, it appears that Preview used to support this before. Some bug is causing this issue.
